# How to `bound' $L^\infty$ by the constant function $1$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, vector-lattices

Let $(S,\mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space and consider the [Riesz space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_space#Examples) $L^\infty=L^\infty(S,\mathcal A, \mu)$ (under point-wise ordering). Let $1_X$ denote the indicator function on $S$ (which is contained $L^\infty$).

Given an arbitrary $f\in L^\infty$, is it possible to find a $\alpha\in\mathbf{R}$ such that $$-\alpha\cdot1_S\le f\le \alpha\cdot 1_S$$ The $\cdot$-symbol denotes the point-wise multiplication, that is $\alpha\cdot 1_S=\alpha\cdot 1_S(x)$ for all $x\in S$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $f \in L^\infty$, we have $|f| \le \|f\|_\infty$ almost everywhere. If we let $\alpha = \|f\|_\infty$, we are done.

Comment: But this bound only works almost everywhere. Sure, you can find a representative of $f$ from same equivalence class for which this works, but in general $f$ can be unbounded. Right?

Comment: @ThomasE. the order structure on $L^\infty$ (as a Riesz space) *is* $f \leq g$ if and only if $g - f \geq 0$ almost everywhere. This is true in every $L^p$ with $0 \leq p \leq \infty$. Pointwise ordering wouldn't make sense for the reason you note.

Comment: @t.b. Thanks. I overlooked that part and it makes perfect sense now.